# how to read/update exchange 2007 calendars from MS Access

Tags: web-services, ms-access, calendar, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

We have Exchange 2007 and have a need for quite complex group scheduling. Group scheduling is useless if the people invited do not see it in their Outlook Calendar of course. The data about when those appointments are to take place and who should be there live in an Excel or Access application.
I bought the Microsoft book "Inside Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 Web Services" and see a lot of web services examples that pretty much assume I know visual studio. In my case I have not done much programming in 15 years and hope to find a way that allows me to connect Access 2007 directly to Exchange 2007 data, not needing to a third complex part in the middle. I have also read an Access book back to front and have an Access programming book, examples there do not seem to talk about Exchange web services?

In short can one (programmatically) talk to Exchange our Outlook appointment information from an office application like MS Access?

Thank you
Bart

Comment: Ideally we need to do this accross accounts, i.e. one central database for about 100 involved users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [CDO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2714320d-c997-4de1-986f-24f081725d36&displaylang=en) to talk to Exchange 2007 from MS Access 2007.

This [MS support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310557) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you !!. I'm worried by MS stating: 
...this follows the MS Lifecycle of Exchange Server 2003, which goes into Extended Support in April 2009. It is recommended that new Exchange development leverage Exchange Web Services, the Outlook Object Model, or the Outlook MAPI Client Library.
Bart

Comment: In that case, I'd say get it working with MS Access now... fix your problem today. Then start tooling up with Visual Studio (VB.Net is not as much of a leap as VB.C#).

Answer (score 0):

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547783/automatically-create-outlook-appointments/551725#551725), there is some sample VBA, which may help. It is also possible to link Exchange tables directly to Access, using Get External Data->Link and selecting Exchange.